# CSS - Do non-IE browsers support the "filter" attribute?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

IE5.5+ has supported the CSS attribute "`filter`" where you convert a color image into grayscale using just CSS.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayscale=1);
```

Do other browsers support a similar CSS tag without using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out: http://snipplr.com/view/2836/grayscale-img-with-css-crossbrowser/

I hope it helps. I would still recommend using server-side for image manipulation, or Photoshop.

Comment: That does not appear to actually work.  The image is covered by a 20% grey box, but the colors are still present, just slightly muted.

Comment: I wanted to delete this post after I tested it. But he accepted it too quickly. And now I suffer from down votes. Oh well.

Answer (score 6):

No.  Filters are tied to ActiveX.

[One example of how to achieve greyscaling in other browsers](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/grayscaling-in-non-ie-browsers/), but it does use JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the ActiveX clarification

Answer (score 1):

No they do not.  Realistically you shouldn't be using those in cross-browser web development unless it is to make IE work in ways the other browsers don't.  The obvious example is PNG support.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure Opera supports some of the MS stuff. Haven't been able to find out exactly what parts they do support.